# Generate table header for nested model?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

how to generate table header for nested model?

In one of my view i need to display Author Detail and all books related to the author.

How to get the table header for BookList in same view?

@model Author gives me Author model details as well as i am able to foreach  Like below but wondering how to get table header ?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BookList)
{
   //////
}
```

my model is like below

```
public class Author
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string DOB {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}

   public List<Books> BookList{get;set;}
}

public class Book
{
   public string BookIdentification {get;set;}
   public string BookName{get;set;}
   public string Year{get;set;}
   public string price{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you are displaying each `Book` in a table row and you want to add a `thead` element with `th` elements displaying _BookIdentification_, _BookName_ etc?

Comment: Yes, I want the header(th) for 'BookIdentification, BookName , Year ,price.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just create them manually? As in `<thead><tr><td>Book Identification</td><td>.....</td></tr><thead>`

Comment: Actually i am trying '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookName)' because in my application text are based on different language.

Comment: Except that `BookList` is collection of books so that wont work. It would need to be `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Books[0].BookName)` but that also wont work if the collection is empty (which it must be at some point) which means you need to resort to using the `ModelMetadata`. You might be better off using a view model and adding  some additional properties to render the headers

Comment: Actually Those above class i my ViewModel only and i attached like '[Display(Name = "Book Name")] for respective property of the model. But this is little strange that if i have only List<Book> then i can get header but i go via Author then i can't create Header for List<book>

Comment: If its a view model, then in `Author` add an additional property `public Book DefaultBook { get; set}` and initialize it to `model.DefaultBook = new Book();` then use can use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DefaultBook.BookName)` When you post back `DefaultBook` will be null but so what.